# Register filter in Java spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, servlet-filters

I am trying to create filter that should be invoked on every request and check if user is authorizated. My implementation is text-book like.

```
@WebFilter("/*")
public class MiddleWareAuth implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        System.out.println("hi");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String xHeader = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getHeader("Authorization");
        System.out.println("I am here");
        System.out.println(xHeader);
    }
}
```

However what troubles me is that i am not sure where i should register the filter, to let spring know that it should put every request through it.

I read that i should use `<filter>` tag in web.xml file , however my project does not have such file.

I am running my project on intelij 2017.

Where should i let spring know to register my filter?

Thanks for help!.

Comment: How do you configure you spring app?

Comment: @jny I am new to spring so i am using Spring initializer in Intelij

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to roll your own rather than using Spring Security?

Comment: @TheHeadRush As said im new to spring , if there is a shortcut to this let me know :) , this is the only way i found so far to achieve middleWare , also i would like to find out the answer

Comment: Spring Security does exactly what you state you want in your first sentence. Check out this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

Comment: Your filter has nothing to do with spring so why should spring be involved here (not to mention that your filter is flawed and actually will break request processing).